# Sort and show two cells in one for each result + formatting

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to make a Top 10 list of people depending on their daily results.
I have a column for people with each row representing a result for that day. On another sheet I want to make a Top 10 list of people plus their result. To make it easy to read, I was thinking to put Person + result in the same cell (eg. `Paul - 3.5%`).

I have the formula to make the Top 10 and put the result with it, but somehow I can't format it correctly to percentage. Here is the basic one:

```
=transpose(query(sort(CONCAT(transpose('perc weekly'!$B$3:$JNK$3),to_percent(transpose('perc weekly'!$B$5:$JNK$5))),transpose('perc weekly'!$B5:$JNK5),FALSE),"limit 10"))
```

I should also add a space between the two values, but that should be easy I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help:

```
=transpose(query(sort(CONCAT(transpose('perc weekly'!$B$3:$JNK$3)&" ",to_percent(transpose('perc weekly'!$B$5:$JNK$5)&"%")),transpose('perc weekly'!$B5:$JNK5),FALSE),"limit 10"))
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the to_percent still doesn't work. it shows something like MRX 0.00432423%

Comment: `TO_PERCENT` doesn't function very well when concatenated into strings. Better to use something like `TEXT(TRANSPOSE('perc weekly'!$B$5:$JNK$5),"0.0%")`.

Comment: perfect! You should have written it as answer so I could have accepted it. :)

Comment: @pnuts Yes, sorry. Btw. "you reading". It took me a while to understand it